# Is it possible to define a uniformly random rational number?

Tags: probability

My question is, is there any meaningful notion of a uniformly random rantional number in $Q \cap [0,1]$?  I would want "uniformity" in the sense that the odds of being in the interval $[a,b]$ are $b-a$.  (Clearly we can't extend this notion to infinite unions of intervals, since $Q$ has Lebesgue measure $0$.)

Comment: Wouldn't those requirements on the probability measure imply that it is Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ (thus answering your question in the negative)?

Comment: No, you wouldn't get Lebesgue measure unless you assume countable additivity.  Also there could be alternatives to measure theory as a whole, hence the open-ended wording of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Countable additivity is an inherent part of the definition of random variable (or probability space, or measure space, ...). Hence this doen't work out.

Comment: What do you mean by "inherent"?  What breaks if you drop it?  Riemann integration seems to work fine for most people after all.